# Find CDF for a stochastic variable

Tags: statistics

I have trouble understanding the relationship between stochastic variables, because, if one says: We have a random variable $X$ defined with $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and a random variable $Y$ defined as $Y=e^X$ - what is the CDF for Y?

I do understand the relationship between the CDF and PDF, but what I'm unsure about is, that if I get assignments, like the one mentioned above, shall I then take the CDF for $X$, and then say, well the CDF for $Y$ is then $exp(CDF\; for\; X)$, or shall I put the PDF in the exponent of e, and then find the CDF from the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way is to calculate the $\rm CDF$ of $Y$ directly **by using the definition**

$$F_{Y}\left(y\right)=P\left(Y\leq y\right)=P\left(e^{X}\leq y\right)=$$

$$=P\left(X\leq \ln y\right)=\begin{cases}0&y\leq 0\\F_{X}\left(\ln y\right)&y>0\end{cases}$$

From here you can easily infer the $\rm PDF$ by differentiation

$$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\frac{{\rm d}F_{Y}\left(y\right)}{{\rm d}y}=\begin{cases}0&y\leq 0\\\frac{F^{\prime}_{X}\left(\ln y\right)}{y}&y>0\end{cases}=\begin{cases}0&y\leq 0\\\frac{f_{X}\left(\ln y\right)}{y}&y>0\end{cases}$$

Comment: I understand that $\frac{{\rm d}F_{Y}(y)}{{\rm d}y}=\frac{{\rm d}F_{X}(\ln y)}{{\rm d}y}$, but how does that become $\frac{F^{\prime}_{X}(\ln y)}{y}$ - I just thought that would be $f_{X}(\ln y)$, why is there a $y$ in the denominator?

Comment: @Frederik This is just the chain rule $$\frac{{\rm d}F_{Y}(y)}{{\rm d}y}=\frac{{\rm d}F_{X}(\ln y)}{{\rm d}y}=\frac{{\rm d}F_{X}(\ln y)}{{\rm d}\ln y}\frac{{\rm d}\ln y}{{\rm d}y}$$

Comment: Sorry for that, I was confused about how to differentiate the function when the CDF has $-\infty$ in the integral, however, I see now, that it just is the chain rule. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $f(x)=e^x$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$
- If $Y=e^X$  then $\mathbb P(Y \le y)= \mathbb P(e^X \le y)= \mathbb P(X \le \log_e(y))$